# Why is RxJava zip operator working on the thread which last emitted value?

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

I'm trying to zip two Observables which emitts on different threads:

```
Observable<String> xxxx1 = Observable.fromCallable((Func0<String>) () -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "First";
})
        .doOnNext(s -> Log.d("TEEEST", "1 onNext " + s + " thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());

Observable<String> xxxx2 = Observable.fromCallable((Func0<String>) () -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Second";
})
        .doOnNext(s -> Log.d("TEEEST", "2 onNext " + s + " thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

Observable.zip(xxxx1, xxxx2, (s1, s2) -> {
    Log.d("TEEEST", "zip func thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return s1.concat(s2);
})
        .map(s -> {
            Log.d("TEEEST", "map thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return s.concat(" mapped");
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(s -> {
            Log.d("TEEEST", "call " + s + " thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
```

And it seems that the zip works on the thread which emitted value as the last one, here is how my logs look like:

First run:

```
D/TEEEST: 2 onNext Second thread RxIoScheduler-3
D/TEEEST: 1 onNext First thread RxComputationScheduler-1
D/TEEEST: zip func thread RxComputationScheduler-1
D/TEEEST: map thread RxComputationScheduler-1
D/TEEEST: call FirstSecond mapped thread main
```

Second run:

```
D/TEEEST: 1 onNext First thread RxComputationScheduler-2
D/TEEEST: 2 onNext Second thread RxIoScheduler-2
D/TEEEST: zip func thread RxIoScheduler-2
D/TEEEST: map thread RxIoScheduler-2
D/TEEEST: call FirstSecond mapped thread main
```

1. Is this behavior documented somewhere?
2. Why it happens so.
3. How to ensure the zip function and all downstream stuff(the `map` operator in my case) works on a particular Scheduler, not on random one.

Answer (score 9):

`zip` does not operate by default on a particular `Scheduler`.

`zip` emits just when it has all the values to zip. So it emits on the same thread it received the last value on.

To ensure all downstream operations happen on a specific scheduler, you'd have to define an `observeOn()` side-effect.

For all downstream operation, observing the zipped result would be sufficient.

```
Observable.zip(...).observeOn(scheduler)
```

For upstream you'd have to observe the observers being zipped on this specific scheduler.

```
Observable.zip(o1.observeOn(scheduler), o2.observeOn(scheduler), ...)
```

Depending on the scheduler you want to use this doesn't guarantee the thread though.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of RXJava is that no operators in RxJava blocks threads while waiting for values from upstream observables, instead of keeping thread and blocking, operators reuse the thread on which values are emitted to it by upstream observers.

The behavior is not limited to zip. You can observe the same behavior with other operators, for example : flatMap.

Threads are picked from the supplied pool as they are available.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to modify @tynn' s code stuff little bit with his permission!

Let say I want to perform two function as below.

```
fetchFromGoogle = fetchFromGoogle.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
fetchFromYahoo = fetchFromYahoo.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
```

Here this way we can use #zip operator,

```
// Fetch from both API 
Observable<String> zipped 
    = Observable.zip(fetchFromGoogle, fetchFromYahoo, new Func2<String, String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(String google, String yahoo) { 
            // Do something with the results of both threads
            return google + "\n" + yahoo;
        }
    });
```

In addition , you can use #concat operator to run the thread one by one.

```
Observable<String> concatenated = Observable.concat(fetchFromGoogle, fetchFromYahoo);
// Emit the results one after another
```

Comment: I just took reference to your schedulars :)

Comment: how this answers the question anyway?